# Hardware requirements for eclipse (indigo) on windows 7 32 bit

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How much ram and processing power are required to run eclipse smoothly?

I plan to build plugins by extending EMF, GEF.

Comment: @amit : I couldn't find it on eclipse.org
Can you point me to url?

Comment: I think this might be helpful .... http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/The_Official_Eclipse_FAQs#Getting_Started

Comment: I did look through it before posting question. Unfortunately it sheds no light on system requirements. Anyway sbegaudeau has listed them based on his experience. So problem solved (or atleast i hope so).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be confortable to build plugins, 2GB of RAM is a minimum since you would need multiple Eclipse instances (at least the instance where you have the code of the plugin and the instance where your plugin is running). For the processor, pretty much anything released in the last 4 years (except low end processor) and you're good.

I had a Core 2 Duo with 2GB of RAM a year ago and while it was a bit slow from time to time, I could do my job with 2/3 Eclipse instances. Now with a Core i7 and 6GB, I run daily with 6+ Eclipse instances without feeling any problem.

Stephane Begaudeau

Comment: Thank you. But i find it weird that there is no official word about it on their site.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum requirement (2gb) mentioned for eclipse is meant for capability of using it. More Ram is good but less is punishing.

For Eclipse Plugin development, I suggest 8gb of Ram. The CPU choice depends on budget. I had i5 3rd gen and I'm sure it would handle plugin development easily. I won't suggest anything lower than i5 3rd gen or i3 5th gen or ryzen 3 2nd gen or ryzen 5 1st gen.

With my experience I'm telling. When I open 1 extra eclipse instance, few browsers tabs, few more applications like postman, the ram usage spikes to 90+ despite of having 8gb ram. Also, I've octa core machine and sometimes I'm able to utilise it fully 100%. Hence, more is good, decide according to budget.

You must not cut cost in RAM. 8gb is the sweet spot for your need. 4gb will perform slow for sure unless your usage is very low like using only eclipse.

Answer (score -6):

Eclipse java code responsible for long time operations(index update) is mostly singlethreaded, so it is 2-core(there is no one core proc on the market with normal power), i think i3 and overclocked as high as possible. 4gb of cheap ram is quite enough, you don't need fast ram for that. I've also suggested small size SSD raid for HDD is you have enough money. But actully it is not about hardware. It is about eclipse algorithms, memory management, bugs and usability.

Comment: "Java is mostly singlethreaded"??? Firstly, the threading nature of Java is based on the program running in it. Secondly, unlike nearly all other programming languages, Java will actually multithread some things itself - for example performing JIT compilation and garbage collection in a different thread to the main program. So Java is actually less "singlethreaded" than other langages.